# Transfer Function from Charge to Voltage

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, transfer-function

I have this circuit I am working on for a personal project with a piezoelectric sensor. It’s essentially a charge amplifier with some extra features. I’m trying to work through the math to get a transfer function of this circuit that relates a charge input Q to voltage out. Would someone be able to help derive a transfer function for me that I can simulate in matlab?

[image]

Comment: Welcome here, little smurf. In order to find the transfer function from generated charge to output voltage, we need the specifics of the piezoelectric sensor itself too. The fact that you put a node "Charge In (q)" on the end of an extended wire, suggests that the sensor will be connected there. Please correct me if I'm wrong and (for instance) C2/R1 is the sensor with C3/R2 the cable. I also don't understand the function of R5 in this otherwise good looking circuit diagram.

Comment: In this instance the sensor is custom made so I don’t have the specs quite yet. I know we get charge out of the sensor and need to determine the voltage relationship. Everything regarding the R and C components is true but there is no R5. C5 serves the purpose of helping with some coupling issues.

Comment: Honestly, I just need to know how to represent a transfer function with an input of charge. I have it solved for a voltage input but I don’t know how to evaluate it for charge.

Comment: Just as an aside: Then I assume you reserved '\$C_1\$' for the sensor itself? Charge going out of the sensor is the current integrated. If you are able to determine the voltage-to-voltage transfer function, I guess the current-to-voltage wouldn't be a problem either?